# Модификация коллекции Dictionary [C#]

Tags: c#

**Всем привет.**

При попытке модификации значений коллекции Dictionary в цикле:

```
// абстрактный пример
foreach (KeyValuePair<String,double> item in dict)
{
    dict[item.Key]=dict.Value;
}
```

в RunTime`е получается ошибка, связанная с невозможностью изменения значений контейнера в цикле.

Мое решение данной проблемы весьма коряво:

```
foreach (string key in dict.Keys.ToArray())
    dict[key]=dict[key]+1;
```

поэтому ищу хорошее решение этой проблемы. Можно ли применить пользовательскую функцию для изменения всех элементов коллекции? Если нет, то можно ли как-то нормпльно модифицировать последовательность в цикле-enumerator`е ?

**Спасибо!**

Comment: Не вижу ничего корявого в прохождении по словарю по ключами...

Answer (score 1):

На время прохода по коллекции сама коллекция становится read-only. (Таким путём язык исключает многочисленные логические проблемы для программиста.)

Итерируйте по ключам. Вам, правда придётся создать *копию* множества ключей, как в вашем примере. Я бы, однако, использовал немного более дешёвый `.ToList()` вместо `.ToArray()`.

Другой возможностью является применение LINQ:

```
dict = dict.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value + 1);
```

Рабочий пример: http://ideone.com/5qxFK1

Answer (score 0):

При обновлении значения элемента в словаре также обновляется внутренний номер версии, что делает недействительным текущий итератор словаря.

Как вариант:

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>
            {
                {"one", 1L},
                {"two", 2L},
            };

        var keys = new List<string>(dict.Keys);

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            dict[key] = dict[key] + 1;
        }
```